# Minimize Portal 2 diskusage

Tags: portal-2

Portal 2 uses 12 GB on my disk if I install it via Steam.

I only have a 60GB SSD in my laptop.

If I only want to play Multiplayer, which files can I safely delete, so the game will still run?

the .vpk files are the largest part of the game, and I tested to move some files and found out, that the game starts, if I remove these files in `\SteamApps\common\Portal 2\portal2\`: `pak01_009.vpk   pak01_013.vpk   pak01_014.vpk, pak01_015.vpk,   pak01_017.vpk,   pak01_018.vpk,   pak01_019.vpk,   pak01_020.vpk and pak01_022.vpk`

(That frees up already 2GB)

Which other files are not needed to play Multiplayer?

Comment: What's your HD situation? I've never been in a position where "what files can I delete from this game and it still work" is a question I ask before "what files on my HD can I backup and delete" or "what games can I uninstall to make room for new games".

Comment: I only have a 60GB SSD in my laptop, and I don have any other large games on it that I could delete

Comment: Then I'm sorry to say the right answer may be "your laptop won't support that game due to your [small SSD size]", just as I wouldn't be surprised to replace the text in brackets with "underpowered video card" or "older processor" or "small RAM amount" for other games.

Comment: It runs fine on my laptop with high resolution and effects, It is just, that I don't need all the single-player part of the game

Comment: My point is not that those other parts aren't up to snuff when you're gaming; I'm saying that for any game and any PC, there's usually (at least) one piece of hardware that's the limiting factor. For this game and for your laptop, it's your SSD. If you had a desktop PC and you didn't have 12 GB to spare, the answer would be "go get a bigger HD/SSD", not "hack the game files".

Comment: What is so bad about asking? sure, if I had the money I could buy a bigger ssd. I still have 2GB left now after installing portal and it works fine. I just would like to free some unneeded stuff. I think it is a good goal to circumvent the costs of a bigger SSD.

Comment: The reason it's a bad question is that any solution would be an unsupported hack. It's one thing if, like Microsoft Word (for example), the Portal 2 installer allowed you to uninstall or turn off features you didn't want to use. It's another if there's no supported way to remove parts of the installation. (Mods, feel free to delete/move my comments to chat.)

Comment: Maybe expensive, but I use Ceedo and run all my steam, including portal 2, off an external harddrive. I use a 500gb non-ssd drive. My main drive is 120gb ssd. I also have a second drive internal 1tb, I never install anything to main drive.  And I moved all my user folders off main drive as well. So only OS runs there, and I have backup should OS fail.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since the .vpk files are the largest part of the game, you can remove these files in `\SteamApps\common\Portal 2\portal2\`: `pak01_009.vpk   pak01_013.vpk   pak01_014.vpk, pak01_015.vpk,   pak01_017.vpk,   pak01_018.vpk,   pak01_019.vpk,   pak01_020.vpk and pak01_022.vpk`

That frees up already **2GB** of disk-space.

Maybe there are more files you can remove, some more testing woul be needed to find out.

Answer (score 14):

You won't be able to delete any of the data and play it.

Steam will force you to re-download all of the content before you can launch the game.

Comment: maybe I can replace some video-files with some small dummy files?

Comment: @rubo77 Possible, but I don't really know. I have never had luck with replacing files on valve games. I have only had success with adding new video files and then changing the .ini files that reference them to play my custom vids.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that replacing them with dummy files will not work. Steam performs an integrity check on core files regularly.

Comment: Also you might get some VAC warns if it's a multiplayer game.

Comment: This is not correct: I added to my Question some **files I could delete without Steam forcing me to re-download** and still play it

Comment: @rubo77 How much of the game were you able to play? Were there any glitches? Where you in offline mode? When you quit/reconnected to steam did steam re download all of the missing files?

Comment: I played multiplayer the first level without problems. Logged out of the game and still Steam didn't try to re-download those files

Answer (score 2):

Rather than deleting files, you should move them to another disk and link them from there (using symbolic Links). I do this myself to free space on my SSD without breaking programms. [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) is a perfect tool if you don't want to use the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the all of the .bsp files in your "maps" directory which do not have names containing "coop" or are part of the main menu.